# AWS IAM access everything except modify admin users

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How do we set up an administrator that can do everything except modify other administrators?
This doesn't quite work...

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This basically disables all IAM actions. To allow something specific, refer to the PowerUserAccess policy (for an example). Or, set Allow for all actions and explicitly deny certain actions on certain resources.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this would be to have some form of identifier for "other administrators" that you can code into the rule.

How can you currently identify an "Administrator"? If part of their username identifies them as an administrator, you could create a rule based on the username.

For example, using a Principal of:

```
arn:aws:iam::123456789012:user/admin-*
```

This would apply to a User with a username of `admin-fred`.